# How did dotnetkicks.com implement their ASP.NET paging?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, paging

I know the [dotnetkicks.com](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/) system is open source so I can view the code myself but I can't make sense of how they did their paging. It's hard to explain but if you goto [dotnetkicks.com](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/) you can play with the paging on their front page.

What I am specifically interested in is how they show the first few pages, then "..." and then the last few pages.

It starts off like this

Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 355 356 Next

Then if you hit page 10 it changes to this

Prev 1 2 ... 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ... 355 356 Next

It's by far my favorite paging system so I'd like to do the same thing on my websites

Comment: Are you asking how you get the pretty urls like www.dotnetkicks.com/page/6, or how pagination actually works?

Comment: i'm asking about how paging actually works. I've added more details to this question.

Comment: He is asking how to generate the pager links. Based on the page count and the current page index what decision(s) to take to generate the page numbers shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Pagination control](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#1tpgUBiru_A/trunk/DotNetKicks/Incremental.Kick/Web/Controls/Navigation/Paging.cs) in the project is fairly straight forward, if you've ever written a paging control. I think what may be confusing you is the use of [urlrewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/) for the /page/n url format.

Comment: Sorry aLassek, i just noticed you had a link to the actual pagination control. I guess I can't get a clearer answer than that

Answer (score 0):

I've written such a control and it took some code... there are plenty decisions to take.

```
public class SimplePagerLinkGenerator : IPagerLinkGenerator
{
    private PagingDisplaySettings _displaySettings;

    public SimplePagerLinkGenerator(PagingDisplaySettings displaySettings)
    {
        this._displaySettings = displaySettings;
    }

    public PageLinkData[] GetPagesLinkData(uint crtPageIndex, uint pageCount, ushort pageSize,
        string urlLinkTemplate)
    {
        int i, crtPage = (int)crtPageIndex, pageCnt = (int)pageCount,
            pgInnerCnt = (int)this._displaySettings.PagesBeforeOrAfterCurrent,
            pgEndCnt = (int)this._displaySettings.PagesShownAtEndingsCount;

        int innerBlockStart = crtPage - pgInnerCnt;
        int innerBlockEnd = crtPage + pgInnerCnt;
        int innerBlockStartNormalized = innerBlockStart < 1 ? 1 : innerBlockStart;
        int innerBlockEndNormalized = innerBlockEnd > pageCount ? pageCnt : innerBlockEnd;

        List<PageLinkData> result = new List<PageLinkData>(2 * pgEndCnt + 3 + 2 * pgInnerCnt);
        for (i = 1; i <= pgEndCnt && i <= pageCount; i++)
            result.Add(new PageLinkData(i, i == crtPage, urlLinkTemplate, pageSize));
        if (i > pageCount)
            return result.ToArray();
        if (innerBlockStart > pgEndCnt + 1)
        {
            result.Add(PageLinkData.Ellipsis);
            for (i = innerBlockStart; i <= innerBlockEndNormalized; i++)
                result.Add(new PageLinkData(i, i == crtPage, urlLinkTemplate, pageSize));
        }
        else
            for (i = pgEndCnt + 1; i <= innerBlockEndNormalized; i++)
                result.Add(new PageLinkData(i, i == crtPage, urlLinkTemplate, pageSize));

        if (innerBlockEnd < pageCount - pgInnerCnt)
        {
            result.Add(PageLinkData.Ellipsis);
            for (i = pageCnt - pgInnerCnt + 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                result.Add(new PageLinkData(i, i == crtPage, urlLinkTemplate, pageSize));
        }
        else
            for (; i <= pageCount; i++)
                result.Add(new PageLinkData(i, i == crtPage, urlLinkTemplate, pageSize));

        return result.ToArray();
    }

    public PagingDisplaySettings DisplaySettings { get { return this._displaySettings; } }
}
```